# Python: change value inside dual key dictionary

Tags: python

So what I'm trying to do is make a dictionary of people and their information but I want to use their names as the main key and have each part of their information to also have a key. I have not been able to figure out how to go about changing the values of their individual information.
I'm not even sure if I'm going about this the right way here is the code.

```
name = raw_input("name")
age = raw_input("age")
address = raw_input("address")
ramrod = {}

ramrod[name] =  {'age': age}, {'address' : address}

print ramrod

#prints out something like this: {'Todd': ({'age': '67'}, {'address': '55555 FooBar rd'})}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a simple nested dictionary:

```
>>> data = {"Bob": {"Age": 20, "Hobby": "Surfing"}}
>>> data["Bob"]["Age"]
20
```

A dictionary is not a pair - you can store more than one item in a dictionary. So you want one dictionary containing a mapping from name to information, where information is a dictionary containing mappings from the name of the information you want to store about the person to that information.

Note that if you have behaviour associated with the data, or you end up with a lot of large dictionaries, a class might be more suitable:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, hobby):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.hobby = hobby

>>> data = {"Bob": Person("Bob", 20, "Surfing")}
>>> data["Bob"].age
20
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close

```
ramrod[name] = {'age': age, 'address' : address}
```